# How to sort particular array position based on the Id in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in gr" 
:key="space.id"
class="val-name">
</div>
```

I have done that logic using the below few line changes in the api call, like

with that, what i am trying to achieve finally i got it. But issue is, i cant expect the array value same all the time. So i have decided to re-arrange the array values based on the ID.

Comment: I'm wondering what the exact goal is. Because I doubt that you provided all information. Your desired array order seems somewhat random. 
If you just want to have a specific order in an array with assumable id/names then you could create a map to run against your API response Array to always sort in a specific order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`orderMap` would be your desired index outcome.

`array` would be your API response.

map `orderMap` with a function that finds the desired index and places it in our `sorted` array.

```js
const orderMap = ['third', 'second', 'first'];

const array = [{name: 'first'}, {name: 'second'}, {name: 'third'}];

let sorted = orderMap.map(function(sortBy){
  return this.find(function(toSort){return toSort.name === sortBy})
}, array)

console.log(sorted);
```

```
// as method -> Result is your response Data. OrderMap the map to order by. 
sortResultSet(result, orderMap) {
  return orderMap.map(function(sortBy){
    return this.find(function(toSort){return toSort.name === sortBy})
  }, result)
}
```

Comment: make a computed value out of it. `computedArray(){ const orderMap=[...]; return orderMap.map(function(element){
  return this.find(function(el, i){return i === element})
}, array);}` where array is your var with the response array

Comment: Or you create a method for it, which is called after successfull response. That's up to you

Comment: @tzuker I updated my Answer. 
orderMap holds the names in the desired order and the find callback returns for each index, the item with the desired name.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a custom sorting function so it sorts them according to your needs.
For eg:

```
function Sort(item1, item2){
  if (item1.name > item2.name)
    return 1;
  else if (item1.name < item2.name)
    return -1;
  else 
    return 0;
}
```

And then call it on the array

```
array.sort(Sort);
console.log(array);
```

If you want to you can omit the function declaration and just pass function as a parameter.

```
array.sort(function (item1, item2) {
  <same code from above>
});
```

And then just add it to the desired object from Vue